# how to send Emails from yahoo mail to the others by (PHP + swiftmailer)?

Tags: php, email, encryption, port, yahoo

is it possible to send Emails from yahoo mail to the others by (PHP + swiftmailer)?

mean which Host?

which port ?

which Encryption ?

i tried :

smtp.mail.yahoo.com

465

ssl

it seems that email is sent , but never recieved!!!! - no error

thanks 4 help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not possible.  Maybe if you have some type of paid yahoo account you'll get real SMTP, but I doubt it.